# KendoUI diagram-Different layout for different data object in list in same kendoDiagram

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a json. 
basic structure of Json is =>

```
{
 "parent1", child:["child1", "child2"],
 "parent2", child:["child1", "child2"]
}
```

the layout of kendo diagram has type:"tree".
At present i have parent1 and parent2 with same subtype:"right" as below.

```
         |-->child1                 |-->child1
parent1--|                 parent2--|     
         |-->child2                 |-->child2
```

I need the layout of parent1 to be with subtype:"right" and of parent2 to be with subtype:"left" in same diagram as below.

```
         |-->child1          child1<--|
parent1--|                            |--parent2
         |-->child2          child2<--|
```

Is there even a way to get this? If yes please help. Thanks!